# Stored procedure with params in excel without Ado.net

Tags: excel

I have a stored procedure with params on sql server 2000 and i am trying to run it from excel 2003.
I did setup the DSN for the db and now when i am in MS Query form Excel, i tried to execute the SP using the syntax
{CALL mystoredProc (?,?,?)}
After i say ok it does ask me for the parameters after that the result set that i am getting has all the column names but no data.
The result set should have atleast 200 rows because i do get them if i run it using the QueryAnalyzer.
Please advice me i am a newbie and apologize if this is a silly question..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ADO?

With ado you can use ADODB.Command, And pass parameters to object using append method.

Other way to your proc don´t work is if your parameter is date and a format is wrong.

if is a date try pass a date with format

```
format(date(),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

In Sql is a default format of dates.

[]´s